# Microsoft Graph API get channel members

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get a list of members in Microsoft teams graph API. I did not find anything in the official documents. I am able to get list of teams and channel but I need to get the list of members to belong to the specific channel. Can anyone have an idea how can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public channels don't have "members".  The Team (basically group) has members.  So you can find the list of members of a channel by listing the [group members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0).

To support [Private channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels) you need to use the [beta API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-beta).
There is no documented API to list the private channel members, but reading between the lines of the [Private Channel Add Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-add?view=graph-rest-beta) API, my guess that if you do a:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<group_id>/channels/<channel_id>/members
```

you will get a list of private members.  In fact it's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels-life-cycle-management) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I was able to access it in v1.0 and may be it is out of beta